# А какие специализированные языки программирования графики знаете вы?

Tags: графика

Когда-то давно я наткнулся на один язык программирования графики [Processing](http://processing.org/), занимательная штука, если честно) но она работает на виртуальной машине явы, а хотелось бы чего-то нативного;) однако, это не суть, просто хочется узнать что еще нового придумали в этом плане, когда-то на хабре засветилась новость о таком языке, на нем создавались поистине красивые сцены да и еще с приятным синтаксисом, но увы, найти не смог. А какие языки программирования графики знаете вы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Языки для создания шейдеров [HLSL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HLSL)  и [GLSL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language). Оба Си-подобны, и служат для программирования графического конвейера

Answer (score 0):

[Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/), [Paper](http://paperjs.org/). Только это не совсем языки программирования, а **Web-Drawing библиотеки**

Comment: @Deonis, это именно язык для программирования графики, вот еще пример http://halide-lang.org/

Answer (score 0):

Шейдеры можно ещё писать на [Cg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cg_(programming_language)). Его плюс в том, что можно использовать как с OpenGL, так и с DirectX.